# Semi dynamic constants in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

For GWT we use static constants to provide internationalization for our users. However, this makes reviewing and editing the texts a tedious process, because if one of our stakeholders has comments, it has to be compiled and deployed to our demo environment again. The solution would be to have some kind of semi dynamic text constants.

What I would like, is that I can compile to some kind of "review mode", and when I do that, the constants are read from a file from the server or database. If possible I would like to be able to edit this file, so stakeholders can modify the texts themselves (using some kind of text edit widget I would have to write for that). Then we can develop, test and demo with these texts. If we are satisfied, we compile for production mode, which uses a old fashioned constants resource bundle, compiled completely in JavaScript.

Does somebody know if something like this exists, or have some pointers on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a very surprising situation that GWT programmers often overlook the usefulness of JSPs and the Dictionary class. Even though many of us had tons of JSP experience prior to using GWT.

**Dictionary class**

You can define your "static" information as javascript var objects in the html hosting file. The Dictionary class can be used to read those javascript objects any time after moduleload.

**JSP**

The HTML "hosting" file, i.e. the html file used for launching GWT need not be an HTML file. It can be a HTML file dynamically generated by a JSP.

If you are familiar with JSP, you could turn an HTML file into a JSP just by changing its extension. Now turn the javascript object section you used for defining GWT "static" information into being dynamically generated by the JSP.

Voila!

I use JSP as the hosting file when I need to generate user- or session- specific "static" information for the GWT client. The JSP could read from the database or from some conditionally chosen text files.