# How can I pass server session variables and attributes to the GWT engine?

Tags: java, gwt, struts2

I am wondering whether we can pass session attributes and parameters from JSP to GWT Entry 
point.

Like I have integrated Struts2 with GWT.

Now, my question is, Can we pass a session attribute from JSP to GWT Entry point?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting why you want to pass session object, after all you want use it in `GWT Servlet` and not in `GWT UI` side am I right?

You can get the session object in GWT Servlet by following ways:

```
  HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
  HTTPSession session = request.getSession();
```

And after that you can user following methods to get and set session attributes:

```
  session.setAttribute("XXX", object);
  session.getAttribute("XXX")
```

EDIT:

I think then there isn't straight forward solution, the workaround can be as follow:

In EntryPoint from `onModuleLoad` call server side code of GWT which will have access to `session` object.

```
  HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
  HTTPSession session = request.getSession();
```

Get the attributes and parameter you want from session object and return it to client in the form of beans.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is JSP + GWT Dictionary class.

Using a JSP (instead of html file) as hosting file, call Dictionary class anytime after GWT on module load.

```
<script>
  var info = {js object structure}; // Use Dictionary class to retrieve info.
</script>
```

[GWT-Platform login + session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065977/gwt-platform-login-session-menagment/9090460#9090460)

[Where to strore config parameteres in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954823/where-to-strore-config-parameteres-in-gwt/8967095#8967095)

[Semi dynamic constants in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425310/semi-dynamic-constants-in-gwt/9459462#9459462)

[Can GWT Properties be used from the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270664/can-gwt-properties-be-used-from-the-server/9287612#9287612)

---

But passing session info to entry point may not be advantageous. The begging question is, what happens when session expires and GWT client is still on the browser?

I guess you could check that if session is stale, you make a window.location call to refresh the GWT client. Which is not a good practice. One of the reasons of using AJAX is not having to say you are sorry (I mean, not having to refresh your page), while conducting client-server data interchanges.

You should pass all sorts of **static** info from server to client thro the JSP+Dictionary way, but not for session.

Your architecture should force re-authentication on session expiration, and the session info should be carried as headers (if you are using REST or RequestBuilder) or carried as part of callback response data structure (if using RPC).

Comment: If there are whole Java Objects residing in the session, then how can can we assign it to javascript `var` ?

Comment: I left out the fact that Dictionary objects are accessed as a hierarchical map, because a var can be a hierarchy of JS objects. Look at the GWT javadoc for Dictionary where there is a simple example. Every var can be accessed thro Dictionary using its var name as key.

Answer (score 0):

I my application, I use hidden boxes in the jsp:

> `<input type="hidden" id="dir_lat" value="<%= request.getattribute("foo") %>"/>`

and then to get the value in  gwt.application:

> `String foo = ((InputElement) doc.getElementById("dir_lat")).getValue() ;`

Comment: what if i want to transfer a whole java object (residing in session attribute) to the server side?

Comment: I don't know !? I guess the simplest (not easiest) should be to serialize/deserialize in hidden box.

Comment: If you need a whole object it would be easiest to use JSON. Look to the struts2 json plugin it will make the serialization quite simple.

Comment: @Quaternion: What about multiple java objects in session? Will it be feasible to use JSon then?

Comment: Well you are going to create a action for each thing you are going to want to get... want user information create a package called json and an action called user. Then just say /json/user. There is no issue about getting multiple objects from the session at once, or from out of a database, or... well see the struts2-json-plugin on the apache.struts site there are a number of questions on SO concerning its use, both using xml and annotations which will be useful. If you are going to cover all the actions in a package with a result type use xml, if on a action by action basis use annotations.

Comment: @Quaternion: So you are suggesting that we should write extra actions and convert all Java object to JSON and then use it in our Entry point. What about the session state variables. Can we also convert them to JSON? Is it a good approach?

Comment: What I recommend is create some actions which display lists of content, using struts2 tags and html.  Then re-create that functionality using ajax and the struts2-json-plugin.  If you do this once then it will make sense.